# OpenLayer4.6.5: Define custom tileImage source in a local directory

Tags: openlayers, qgis

I create a custom tileImage server in a local directory (named mapnik) with QTiles plugin in Qgis. I would like to load these images and display a map with openLayer library. This is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileImage({
          url: './mapnik/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
        })
      });
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
      map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([77.5578658823407, -37.836996810851645], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
      map.getView().setZoom(11);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But my map is not displayed in my web page and in my console I have an error, it is writing 'TypeError: b is null'.

I suppose than I forgot some parameters in the ol.layer.Tile object configuration, but I don't find which parameters. Somebody has a solution? 
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ol.source.XYZ (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_XYZ-XYZ.html) instead of ol.source.TileImage which is a base class.

Comment: Thanks, I find a solution, indeed I used ol.source.XYZ and I changed my URL parmeter, initially it was './mapnik/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png' now it's './mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' without '-', and that works!